# Multiplying floats and ints

Tags: python, input

So I am trying to create a program that will tell you your percentage in the class based on the each sections(test, hw, ect.) percent.

```
T1 = input('Test 1 Score ')
T2 = input('Test 2 Score ')
F1 = input('Final Test Score ')
HW = input('Homework Score ')
IC = input('Quiz Score ')
LAB = input('Lab Score ')

print((float(T1+T2) * 0.19) + (float(F1) * 0.22) + (float(HW) * 0.18) + (float(IC) * 0.08) + (float(LAB) * 0.14))
```

For example I was using

```
T1 = 100,    
T2 = 100,    
F1 = 100,    
HW = 0,
IC = 100,    
LAB = 100,
```

For some reason when it is doing the `(T1 + T2)` its coming back with `19019.0` as a result

Answer (score 2):

T1 and T2 in this context are strings, and you are basically concatenating strings

try to `float(T1) + float(T2)`

Comment: I changed it to what you said and it is now returning the print(float(T1)+float(T2)*.19) with
119

Comment: print((float(T1)+float(T2))*.19) so it first add and only then multiply :)

Answer (score 1):

T1 = "100"
T2 = "100"

T1+T2 = "100100"

"100100" * 0.19 = 19019.0

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to include `float (T1 + T2)` if you just use `(int(T1)+ int(T2))` python will automatically change the int to a float when you multiply, and this should also solve your problem.